# Help with building matrices

Tags: matrix

I am a complete beginner in Mathematica and I have a small problem.

[image]

I have this three matrices (A,B and C) and with them I have to build larger matrix M which looks like this.

[image]

What would be the easiest way to do this Mathematica?

So far I have this:

```
A = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];
B = Table[Subscript[b, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];
C = Table[Subscript[c, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];
```

Comment: Useful functions here: Plus, Span, ArrayFlatten, ConstantArray.

Comment: [Avoid using subscripts until you become an expert](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/193)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this kind of step-by-step assignment is probably the easiest for you to follow and apply generally at this time:

```
aa = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];
bb = Table[Subscript[b, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];
cc = Table[Subscript[c, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];

new = ConstantArray[0, {12, 12}];

new[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 6]] = aa[[1 ;; 3]];
new[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]] += cc[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]];
new[[1 ;; 3, 4 ;; 6]] += bb[[1 ;; 3, 4 ;; 6]];
new[[4 ;; 6, 4 ;; 6]] = cc[[4 ;; 6, 4 ;; 6]];
new[[7 ;; 9, 1 ;; 3]] = aa[[4 ;; 6, 4 ;; 6]] + bb[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]];
new[[7 ;; 9, 4 ;; 6]] = bb[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]] + cc[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]];
new[[10 ;; 12, 10 ;; 12]] = aa[[4 ;; 6, 1 ;; 3]];

new // MatrixForm
```

<sub>$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 a_{1,1}+c_{1,1} & a_{1,2}+c_{1,2} & a_{1,3}+c_{1,3} & a_{1,4}+b_{1,4} & a_{1,5}+b_{1,5} & a_{1,6}+b_{1,6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 a_{2,1}+c_{2,1} & a_{2,2}+c_{2,2} & a_{2,3}+c_{2,3} & a_{2,4}+b_{2,4} & a_{2,5}+b_{2,5} & a_{2,6}+b_{2,6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 a_{3,1}+c_{3,1} & a_{3,2}+c_{3,2} & a_{3,3}+c_{3,3} & a_{3,4}+b_{3,4} & a_{3,5}+b_{3,5} & a_{3,6}+b_{3,6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{4,4} & c_{4,5} & c_{4,6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{5,4} & c_{5,5} & c_{5,6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{6,4} & c_{6,5} & c_{6,6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 a_{4,4}+b_{1,1} & a_{4,5}+b_{1,2} & a_{4,6}+b_{1,3} & b_{1,1}+c_{1,1} & b_{1,2}+c_{1,2} & b_{1,3}+c_{1,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 a_{5,4}+b_{2,1} & a_{5,5}+b_{2,2} & a_{5,6}+b_{2,3} & b_{2,1}+c_{2,1} & b_{2,2}+c_{2,2} & b_{2,3}+c_{2,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 a_{6,4}+b_{3,1} & a_{6,5}+b_{3,2} & a_{6,6}+b_{3,3} & b_{3,1}+c_{3,1} & b_{3,2}+c_{3,2} & b_{3,3}+c_{3,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$</sub>

Note: I renamed `A`, `B`, `C` to `aa`, `bb`, `cc` because you should avoid starting user Symbols with capital letters; for example `C` is as protected `` System` `` Symbol:

> Set::wrsym: Symbol C is Protected. >>

Answer (score 1):

```
A = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];
B = Table[Subscript[b, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];
Cc = Table[Subscript[c, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];

m0 = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];

M = ArrayFlatten[{

   {A[[;; 3, ;; 3]] + Cc[[;; 3, ;; 3]]   ,A[[;; 3, 4 ;; 6]] + B[[;; 3, 4 ;; 6]], m0, m0},
   {m0                                   , Cc[[4 ;; 6, 4 ;; 6]]                , m0, m0},
   {A[[4 ;; 6, 4 ;; 6]] + B[[;; 3, ;; 3]],B[[;; 3, ;; 3]] + Cc[[;; 3, ;; 3]]   , m0, m0},
   {m0                                   , m0                                  , m0, A[[4 ;; 6, ;; 3]]}

        }];
```

Or, equivalently :

[image]